# Fix for Chrome to save SSD?

Tags: google-chrome, ssd

Google Chrome, like Firefox, keeps rewriting its full session state, which can write well over 10 GB per day  - a disaster for those using solid state disks, which have a limited number of lifetime write cycles. For Firefox, this can be fixed by using `about:config` and modifying `browser.sessionstore.interval` to a large value; this sets the number of milliseconds between times the browser stores the session. How do I fix this for Chrome?

Answer (score 9):

'10 GB per day' on a 250 GB disk mean 1 full write in 25 days; with maybe 3000 cycles lifetime, that gives you 75000 days or *~200 years*.
Are you really planning to use your SSD that long?

I am running Chrome on a machine with an SSD since three years, continuously and hard-used, and I happened to check the SSD last week, it reports 0.17% use of its lifetime. That mean it is 'used up' after 1800 years; that should be acceptable.

I understand that this doesn't answer your question, but it makes it kind of 'doesn't matter any more'

Comment: Out of interest, what software did you use to report the lifetime usage of the SSD?

Comment: That was six months ago, I don't remember for sure. Maybe CrystalDisk, but I will have to try again to now for sure

Comment: This is not an answer; it should not even be a comment as it has no value in addressing the subject.